# Newton iteration for finite difference simple case

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-differences, newton-raphson

For the equation : $u_t + u_x = 0$

If I discritize with finite difference I get :

$$u^{m+1} - u^m + \frac{\Delta t}{2 \Delta x} (u^m_{n+1}-u^m_{n-1}) = 0$$

Where $m$ = time, $n$ is the $x$ axis, $u^0$ is known initial condition, assume boundaries known but I won't discuss them for simplicity.

I know how to solve this with time steps for finite difference, but what if  I want to solve this with Newton-Raphson Method? Do I consider $u^m$ when calculating the Jacobean, or just $u^{m+1}$?

if I only consider $u^{m+1}$ then I think the Jacobean becomes an identity matrix and the update step becomes : 
$$\vec{u^{k + 1}}=\vec{u^k}-
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} (
\vec{u^k} -\vec{u^m}+ \frac{\Delta t}{2 \Delta x}(\vec{u^m_{n + 1}} - \vec{\vec{u^m_{n - 1}}})
)$$

Where $\vec{u^k}$ is the current guess for $u^{m+1}$

Ignoring boundary conditions, is this correct? Seems to easy with

Comment: Why do you want to apply Newton-Raphson, your update is already explicit? And centered differences in $x$ are unstable for your transport equation. Upwinding will use backward differences.

Comment: I want to apply Newton-Raphson to a more complicated non linear problem, and so I am trying on this equation as a learning exercise.

Comment: Newton is used for semi or fully implicit schemes, so in your discretization of $u_x$ you would use $m+1$ for some or all of the terms. When the equation is nonlinear, it is not possible to solve explicitly for $u^{m+1}$ and so one uses a root finding algorithm, like Newton's method. For explicit schemes, it makes no sense to use Newton, and there is no analogy. Do you know how to use Newton's method to solve $F(x)=0$?

Comment: $x^{k+1} = x^k - J^{-1}f(x^k)$, where $x^k$ converges to the root (in most cases) given no local minimum, and J is Jacobean.

The explicit scheme is just an algebraic equation. It should be fine to use a root finding algorithm for an algebraic equation if you want to, no?

You said m+1, so am I right that the Jacobean is just a identity matrix in this case?